# Creating multiple java objects/ cleaning up a project

Tags: java, class, object

First time poster. So please be kind if this is done incorrectly. Full disclosure this is for a intro java class however I have already turned this project in I just want to rework it to fix my mistakes

Main issue is just understanding the fundamentals of objects and classes. The program is supposed to simulate a Yahtzee 5 dice roll. I need to create a dice class and then create 5 dice objects that roll a random value between 1 and 5. Currently I have created a class called OneDice:

```
public class OneDice {

    private int die;   // variable for a dice

    public OneDice() {
        roll();  //constructor
    }

    public void roll() {// random 
        die = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
    }


    public int value() {

    // return the value of the die variable
    return die;
}
```

Next we are to create a Yahtzee class that "hold five dice objects" here is what I create:

```
public class Yahtzee  {
    private int dice1;
    private int dice2;
    private int dice3;
    private int dice4;
    private int dice5;

    public Yahtzee(){
          yahtzeeRoll(); //constructor
    }

    public void yahtzeeRoll(){          
         OneDice diceA = new OneDice();
         OneDice diceB = new OneDice();
         OneDice diceC = new OneDice();
         OneDice diceD = new OneDice();
         OneDice diceE = new OneDice();
         dice1 = diceA.value(); 
         dice2 = diceB.value(); 
         dice3 = diceC.value();
         dice4 = diceD.value();
         dice5 = diceE.value();
    }

    public void printYahtzee(){ //prints the dices and graphics
       System.out.println("dice 1 comes up= " + dice1);
       System.out.println("dice 2 comes up= " + dice2);
       System.out.println("dice 3 comes up= " + dice3);
       System.out.println("Dice 4 comes up= " + dice4);
       System.out.println("Dice 5 comes up= " + dice5);
    }
```

Now i understand that this is terrible coding. With the `dice1 = diceA.value` ect lines. How do I created five individual instances of OneDice object that can be assigned to each individual dice. I know this is really basic stuff. I have tried rereading my text book and reading things online and just cant figure it out. Thanks in advance. I hope that his topic is not too broad :(

Full instructions:

Create a class that simulates a single six-sided die. A die can have the values from 1 to 6. The constructor should set the die to a random value (i.e. the die should never start with the value of zero). It should have two methods. One, called roll, randomly sets the die to a new value. The other, called value, returns the current value of the die.

Create a second class called Yahtzee that holds five die objects. Have a method called roll that rolls all five dice. Have a method called show that displays the values of each of the five dice.

Your main class should roll the five dice, display the result, and then ask the user if he wants to roll the dice again.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com


Comment: Use arrays or `java.util.List` or `java.util.ArrayList`

Comment: The main question is what your actual assignment was. If you need an instance for each dice list ist your feature of choice assuming you learned that already. But if you only need the result with no specifics how to reach it, it should not matter whether you roll onve with 5 dice or five times with only one of them.

Comment: @Azad There is no reason to use a list or arraylist, when you know the length of the data at compile time you should use an array.

Comment: @Robadob: how about if you want to add more objects in the run time?

Comment: On a small point you are creating a random double and then casting to an int. Do you know that if you create a new Random() you can get random integers directly?

Comment: @Azad Nowhere in his specification does he say he needs to add at runtime, he states 5. Hence a known length at creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite your Yhatzee class to utilise arrays like this (this assumes you want to keep separate instaces of dice, personally I would so that I could recall the values of specific dice later, however if that is never going to be necessary, you have no specific reason to do so);

```
public class Yahtzee  {
    private Dice[] dice;
    private final int DICE_COUNT=5;
    public Yahtzee(){
        dice=new Dice[DICE_COUNT];
        for(int i =0;i<DICE_COUNT;i++)
            dice[i] = new Dice();
        yahtzeeRoll(); //constructor
    }
    public void yahtzeeRoll(){         
        for(int i =0;i<DICE_COUNT;i++)
            dice[i].roll();
    }
    public void printYahtzee(){ //prints the dices and graphics         
        for(int i =0;i<DICE_COUNT;i++)
            System.out.println("dice "+(i+1)+" comes up= " + dice[i].value());
    }
}
```

Comment: actually that is a great solution. I wanted to avoid an array as well we have not covered them / i dont have a great understanding of how to use them. But I took an intro to programming course that covered the basic concept of arrays and it seemed that his would be a much more efficient solution. So I may do some more research on arrays.

Comment: Arrays are useful when you need to hold a known number of items of the same type (and perform identical actions on them). The 'efficiency' between the 2 solutions at runtime would be negligible, it just saves you writing extra code. One of the first programs I wrote when I first learnt programming was mastermind, I used no arrays or iteration, the code ended up being many thousands of lines of repeated statements :p

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `ArrayList` or an `Array` to hold the values and use a for-loop to create the values and a for-loop to print the values, like so:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Yahtzee {

    // Two options, either keep a list of dices, or a list of the value of
    // dices, the first option is more sensible to me
    // Option 1
    private List<OneDice> dices;

    public Yahtzee(int numberOfRolls) {
        this.dices = new ArrayList<>();
        yahtzeeRoll(numberOfRolls);
    }

    public void yahtzeeRoll(int numberOfRolls) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRolls; i++) {
            OneDice dice = new OneDice();
            dices.add(dice);
        }
    }

    public void printYahtzee() {
        for (OneDice dice : dices) { // This is an enhanced for loop
            System.out.println("Dice rolled: " + dice.value());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Yahtzee yahtzeeGame = new Yahtzee(5);
        yahtzeeGame.printYahtzee();
    }
    }
```

Comment: There is no reason to use a list or arraylist, when you know the length of the array at creation. Only then if you don't know the length of the collection, you would choose which implementation of List based on how you will be using it. A linked list provides fast insertion, deletion and sequential access, whereas arraylists provide fast random access and must be resized when the number of items increases over the hidden size of the array.

Also you should init your ArrayList as `new ArrayList<OneDice>();` for readability.

Comment: All very valid points but out of context, none of those are of concern to OP.

Comment: Also every time you call your yhatzee roll your adding more dice to your list rather than rerolling the dice. You should clear the list. Point is in context, because you shouldn't teach people bad habits, they take forever to correct.

Comment: OP stated he needed five different objects, I understand where you are coming from and your solution is the better one but I don't like to put the horse before the cart, OP is clearly new to programming and doing things simple is what matters then.